# How to change status bar / navigation bar color/brightness with respective to theme?

Tags: flutter, material-design, themes, flutter-getx

Using **Getx** for theming, but facing some issue with changing status bar icon brightness based on light / dark theme.

I found two ways.

**First**.

```
 WidgetsBinding.instance!.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
   SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(overlayStyle);
 });
```

This need to be called during initState().

**Second**.

```
AnnotatedRegion<SystemUiOverlayStyle>()
```

This widget also does work properly.
Is there any other method which can be implemented for this purpose?

P.S. Using Flutter 2.8.0

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`ThemeData`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ThemeData-class.html) to change brightness of the whole app based on dark/bright.

All your themes customisation can be done using this. Below is an example for brightness and primary color.

```dart
ThemeData(
    brightness: Brightness.dark, // or Brightness.light (for dark or light)
    // .........
    primarySwatch: Colors.orange, // for changing primary color
),
```